# apply function to a subset of a variable length

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have got a list

```
list = Row[{#}] & /@ Range[100]
```

and I want to apply function f to the following elements:

```
sublist = Row[{5 #}] & /@ Range[20]
```

It is easy when I specify indexes I want to transform. For instance,

```
MapAt[f, list, {{1}, {5}}]
```

works OK. As soon as I create a new list and use it as "Part":

```
h = Row[{5 #}] & /@ Range[20]; 
MapAt[f, list, h]
```

it fails. I suppose that the crux of the problem is using # simultaneously in two arrays - list and h, but I am new to Mathematica and can't figure it out. Is there any way to work with arrays of arbitrary length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapAt` needs a plain list, not items wrapped in `Row`.  If you omit `Row` from `h` it works.  Note your function `f` is applied to `Row[{5}]`, not just `{5}`.  Are you sure you need to use `Row` at all?

[image]

Comment: I realized that there's no need for `Row`. Thank you very much!